# Obj C - Compressing an image from the file path

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is what I've got thus far:

```
NSString *value = call.arguments[@"filePath"];
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:value];
NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.3);
```

What I'm trying to do is compress the image on that file path by replacing the same image. However, I seem to be getting the same size for the image.. Is the code correct?

```
FILE SIZE BEFORE::10640696
FILE SIZE AFTER::10640696
```

Comment: Why am I being persecuted for asking this?

Answer (score 0):

To save the file, all I had to do was add the following line:

```
[data writeToFile:value atomically:YES];
```

Thanks for all the downvotes, hate and no help.

Comment: Is it possible that your image was already in JPEG format, and that UIImageJPEGRepresentation realized that, and just sent you back your image in the format it already had?

Comment: PS Upvoted because it's a legitimate programming question.